# post fan page stream to iphone app

Tags: iphone, android, facebook, appcelerator

i'm wanting to display the stream of a facebook fan page within an iphone app. i know it's possible to do this with a twitter stream, but wasn't sure if it was available to do w/ facebook fan page stream.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can call any web API, so yes, it is possible.

The Titanium.Facebook documentation is [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module). You might have to read official Facebook developer documentation.

There isn't any Facebook fan page examples in the sample app (Kitchen Sink). You've got to code it by yourself.

Good luck!